# How to access XAMPP on local computer after DirectoryRoot has been assigned to a directory?

Tags: apache, web, xampp, lampp

I have just set up my server to work with the outside world on XAMPP.
I have way too many questions about it, but at least the first of them is, How do I get to access the xampp control panel, being a sibling of my homesite, once the RootDirectory has been assigned?

```
htdocs
|
|--->mysite.com
|
|--->xampp
```

even when I was fiddling around the `VirtualHosts` I had a weird problem accessing certain js and css files from the `xampp` directory, returning a `403 forbidden`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to: localhost/here-your-site.

You must be content on htdocs/here-your-site